# Cannot find specific entry when searching for the title

Tags: google-search-appliance

I'm having a Google Mini set up at my company. We're using it to search documents, such as PDFs or DOCs in our document management system (DMS).

I'm having a DOC, that is only found by it's ID (some uuid) that is stored in the URL, but not by it's title "approval".

The file is stored at "http://dms.local/?id=36C71D9C-155D-0010-0117A0E6FC109FF0"

---

Example of the URL I'm calling **with term "Approval"**:

http://googlesearchappliance.local/search?q=Approval&output=xml_no_dtd&client=intranet&site=DMS&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&filter=0&num=1000

This returns about 20 documents, that have the term "approval" in the title or the summary, but not the document I'm looking for.

---

Example of the URL I'm calling **with the ID**:

http://googlesearchappliance.local/search?q=36C71D9C-155D-0010-0117A0E6FC109FF0&output=xml_no_dtd&client=intranet&site=DMS&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&filter=0&num=1000

Which returns this:

```
<RES SN="1" EN="1">
  <M>1</M>
  <XT/>
  <R N="1" MIME="application/octet-stream">
    <U>
      http://dms.local/?id=36C71D9C-155D-0010-0117A0E6FC109FF0
    </U>
    <UE>
      http://dms.local/%3Fid%3D36C71D9C-155D-0010-0117A0E6FC109FF0
    </UE>
    <T>Approval</T>
    <RK>10</RK>
    <CRAWLDATE>18. Mai 2015</CRAWLDATE>
    <FS NAME="date" VALUE="2014-12-19"/>
    <S>
      Approval for something (some text) (some other text<br> even more text). (text <b>...</b>
    </S>
    <LANG>ja</LANG>
    <HAS>
      <L/>
      <C SZ="" CID="TV38Tk04ongJ" ENC="UTF-8"/>
    </HAS>
  </R>
</RES>
```

---

That doesn't make any sense to me, and I don't know where to search. Have I excluded or forgotten something in the search-URL?

I tried to use any other terms or phrases that occur inside the document.

I have tried to re-index the whole document management system.

I also went through filters that we have set up in the Google Mini admin console, but all documents share the same link (e.g. http://dms.local/?id=some-uuid).

We're having a maximum of 50'000 pages in our Mini, but I can't find how many pages we're already having.

Our Mini is running on GSA 5.0.4, Build-ID 10000175.0.0

Comment: Have you tried running this query against the default frontend and the default collection using this URL?
http://googlesearchappliance.local/search, which should redirect to the default frontend.

That's a very old GSA version you mentioned. Is this a Google Mini (the blue server)?

Comment: Yes, it's a blue box and was called "Google Mini" that time. It's currently installed in the DMZ where I don't have the keys, but as far as I can remember, it was all blue when we installed it. Will try your tip as soon as possible.

Comment: The URL you provided redirects me to our intranet start page http://intranet.local/. I have to say, that we're actually invoking our Google Mini via IP, e.g. http://111.11.1.111/search?etc... Does this make a difference? I changed it to http://googlesearchappliance.local/ to make things a little bit clearer.

Comment: Hi Boris,
Yes, just hit the Mini directly without adding any additional query parameters to get to the default frontend and see what happens.
Unfortunately, the Minis have been deprecated so you're using an unsupported product now.
If your company has the budget I'd definitely recommend you look at updating your Mini to a new GSA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether this will help or not. Just give a try.
Add `&lr=lang_ja` to your first query.

http://googlesearchappliance.local/search?q=Approval&output=xml_no_dtd&client=intranet&site=DMS&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&filter=0&num=1000**&lr=lang_ja**

Fire this query, you should get the document you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I tried "lang_de" (german) too, which worked neither.

Comment: So sad..:( I have no other clue. Open support ticket with Google.

Comment: Actually I found out this was the solution. Unfortunately, the browser/proxy did cache the results, so nothing changed. I changed the language-setting in my GSA-Admin to "all" instead of "german only" and now it works. Thanks a lot!